# Удаление из MongoDB с помощью C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Здравствуйте, у меня есть необходимость из базы данных на MongoDB удалять документ, по значению одного из полей в нем. Изначально в базе лежит одно значение по умолчанию, затем с помощью C# я могу просто добавить еще одно значение используя команду `coll.InsertOne(cust_to_write)`. `cust_to_write` содержит следующие поля :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы при добавлении еще одного элемента выполнялась проверка с базой данных, мол, есть ли уже такой `UserId`, я реализовал это так:

```
var temp_cust = coll
    .Find(b => b.UserId == cust_to_write.UserId)
    .ToListAsync()
    .Result;
foreach (var customer in temp_cust)
{
    if (customer.UserId.Equals(cust_to_write.UserId))
    {
        coll.DeleteOne(customer);
    }
}
```

Но программа выдаёт следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не удается преобразовать из "RestService.Models.SyncProfileRequest" в "MongoDB.Driver/FilterDefinition"

По сути, при попытке добавить элемент с уже существующим `UserId`, я пытаюсь удалить старый элемент, а затем на его место просто записываю новый. Но все упирается в эту проблему. Подскажите что можно сделать?

Comment: У вас часть имени типа потерялась...

Comment: Какой тип у переменной cust_to_write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeleteOne`, как и `DeleteMany`, ожидает фильтр для поиска удаляемого объекта, а не сам объект. Т.е. вам нужно что-то вроде:

```
coll.DeleteMany(
    Builders<SysProfileRequest>.Filter.Eq(c => c.UserId, cust_to_write.UserId)
);
```